# Buck Regulator under load

Tags: voltage, load, switching-regulator

[image]  I have built a buck regulator with a Texas Instruments LM5575-Q1. It was designed to handle an input range of 9-75V and output 6V at 500mA.

When I have no load it does measure 6V but as I increase the load the voltage drops. With a load as the input voltage goes up the output goes down. Thus full load and 75V is worst case scenario.

Any suggestions as to why this might be the case?

EDIT:
The first scope picture is the switching pin with no load, 5V per division.
The second scope picture is the switching pin with a 13ohm resistor for load, 20V per division.

[image]

[image]

[image]

EDIT: picture of the board. It is a battery monitor board, a Particle Photon is powered by the buck regulator in question and measures up to 4 batteries that are connected in series. The issue was first noticed when we added the 4th battery in series the photon would constantly reboot itself. It was determined to happen when the photon tried to communicate via Wi-Fi it pulled more current and the voltage dropped enough to reboot but then came right back on.

Comment: Is the switch node clean and jitter-free during loaded operation?  The schematic looks OK, so I would look for layout issues with the compensation and/or current sense.

Comment: Is there much ripple on the output? Have you looked around the voltage feedback circuit to see what is happening when the output voltage drops?

Comment: What type of inductor are you using, is it rated for the current you're loading the converter with ? See the relevant section in the datasheet ! If the inductor is not rated for the current I would expect the behaviour you describe because the inductor saturates and it cannot convert more energy to the output.

Comment: The inductor saturates at 700mA.

Comment: The output looks really clean. The feedback is also dropping with the output, so the chip should be seeing the drop.

Comment: The switching pin picture does not look like a buck to me...

Comment: @VladimirCravero The second picture looks OK, maybe 68V in, low duty cycle because of the conversion ratio.  The first picture is probably DCM ringing at light/no load, but hard to tell because the time scale isn't given.  Still sounds like a layout/ground issue to me.

Comment: Time scale is 1microsecond

Comment: @JohnD I agree. OP, can you possibly snap a picture of your setup?

Comment: Inductor looks OK to me, so not the problem.

Comment: Perhaps re-examine the inductor... The reason will reveal itself if you model the peak switching currents in it. It may be rated for 700mA, however the peak switching currents will be approximately double the output current. The LM5575 data sheet indicates how to calculate the switching currents. Ensure that inductor saturation occurs above max switching current. Also, consider reviewing your compensation network. Non-optimised values will lead to instability and control loop issues.

Comment: @Martin The switching frequency is about 275KHz, so with 75V in and 6V out the inductor ripple current is in the neighborhood of 100mA or so.  Max inductor current is < 600mA.  Maybe not as much margin as one would like but not likely to be saturating.

Comment: Assuming the second scope image is with 70V in and 6V out, the duty cycle should be around 1:10 (on:off). The image shows something more like 1:20. The IC is terminating the on-period too early for some reason. The first thing to look at may be the FB pin right at the IC.

Comment: @rioraxe has a good point, I didn't look at the scope photo closely enough to see that the duty cycle isn't what it should be.  No surprise if the voltage ISN'T where it should be.  The layout looks suspect with the inductor located on the opposite side of the board from the converter and far from the catch diode.

Comment: In the datasheet schematic, there is a dot between the feedback resistors that set the output voltage. In the schematic you posted, I don't see a dot between R21 and R22. If I were you, my next would be to double-check and make sure R21 and R22 are really connected to C6 and U1pin6.

Comment: Another thing I would check: Is maybe the regulator working perfectly, but then we're getting an unwanted voltage drop across the resettable fuse F1? That can be fixed by moving the fuse "upstream" so the U1 regulates the voltage *downstream* of the fuse rather than "upstream" of the fuse.

Comment: Based on what everyone has suggested I have proven the layout is my primary issue. I removed C1 and L1 and attached them with leads much closer to the chip and saw moderate improvement, I am sure having them attached to the board closer will make it even better. The re-settable fuse was removed to see if that was part of the issue and it made no difference